# How to turn Caps Lock into AltGr?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I need `AltGr` a lot for the purpose of `{`,`[`,`]`,`}`,... and it is uncomfortable to only have it available for my right hand. So, I'd like to change `Caps Lock` into `AltGr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Keyboard" > Typing:

Set value of "Alternative Characters Key" to "Caps Lock"

Comment: `setxkbmap -option "lv3:caps_switch"`